# Cassandra copy command is giving OverflowError

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I am new with Cassandra and running DataStax Cassandra 4.8.14.

My cluster is as:

> 3 nodes - cassandra
>
> 3 nodes - solr search by DataStax

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace1.table1 (
    id bigint,
    is_dir boolean,
    dir text,
    name text,
    created_date timestamp,
    size bigint,
    solr_query text,
    status text,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, is_dir, dir, name)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (is_dir ASC, dir ASC, name ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX keyspace1_table1_created_date_index ON keyspace1.table1 (created_date) USING 'com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex';
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX keyspace1_table1_size_index ON keyspace1.table1 (size) USING 'com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex';
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX keyspace1_table1_solr_query_index ON keyspace1.table1 (solr_query) USING 'com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex';
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX keyspace1_table1_status_index ON keyspace1.table1 (status) USING 'com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.Cql3SolrSecondaryIndex';
```

Command executed:

```
COPY keyspace1.table1 TO '/tmp/table1.csv';
```

I was trying to execute copy command and got the following error:

```
<stdin>:10:Error for (None, -9207222088349382333): OverflowError - date value out of range (will try again later attempt 1 of 5)
<stdin>:10:Error for (-2699117314734179807, -2639913056120220671): NoHostAvailable - ('Unable to complete the operation against any hosts', {}) (permanently given up after 95000 rows and 1 attempts)
<stdin>:10:Error for (4414337294902011474, 4418434771303296337): NoHostAvailable - ('Unable to complete the operation against any hosts', {}) (will try again later attempt 1 of 5)
<stdin>:10:Error for (-835790340821162882, -820685939947495393): NoHostAvailable - ('Unable to complete the operation against any hosts', {}) (permanently given up after 49000 rows and 1 attempts)
```

Can anyone please tell me what it means?

Thanks.

Comment: I think your csv is not in correct format. Show sample data from your csv

Comment: Cassandra is writing to csv. Why csv format can be an issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure to remove all rows with created_date > 9999-12-31 23:59:59+0000. It's a bug in Cassandra 2.1 (DSE 4.8.14). Use DSE 5.0 instead.

Here is the JIRA:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10625

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Good think to know. Now, how can identify the rows which have out of range date? I ran a query and the result as follows:

```
select id,created_date from table1  where solr_query = '{"q":"*:*","sort":"created_date desc"}' limit 2;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/dse/resources/cassandra/bin/cqlsh", line 1124, in perform_simple_statement
    rows = self.session.execute(statement, trace=self.tracing_enabled)
  File "/usr/share/dse/resources/cassandra/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-2.7.2-2fc8a2b.zip/cassandra-driver-2.7.2-2fc8a2b/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1602, in execute
    result = future.result()
  File "/usr/share/dse/resources/cassandra/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-2.7.2-2fc8a2b.zip/cassandra-driver-2.7.2-2fc8a2b/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3347, in result
    raise self._final_exception
OverflowError: date value out of range
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Datastax Solr but could you try `select * from table1 where created_date > '9999-12-31' allow filtering;` first? From CQL shell? Assuming the @cdatta suggested problem?

Comment: Thanks. But looks like I am in a messy situation:
Select * from table1 where created_date > '9999-12-31' limit 10 allow filtering ;
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Solr search queries only supported on the 'solr_query' field"

Comment: OK, what if you use `id, created_date`, for example, instead of `*` in your query? Since it complains about `solr_query` field?

Comment: Same error:
 select id from table1  where created_date > '9999-12-31' allow filtering;
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Solr search queries only supported on the 'solr_query' field"

Comment: OK, sorry, as I said, not familiar with Datastax Solr, there apparently are some intricacies.